# I want to push notification to specific user from the admin using firebase with flutter and node js

Tags: node.js, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to send notification to user from admin and from user to admin by sending the token of user from node js backend to firebase to handle the message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate your Flutter app and NodeJS backend with Firebase. Please, refer to the docs for detailed instructions and ask a new specific question if you have a more specific doubt.

- [FlutterFire docs for app integration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/)
- [Firebase docs for server integration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/)
- [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin)